# Apache Spark: reduceByKey function stops Java-application

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

after long time of searching it can't be helped and i need to ask you! I want to do a simple Word Count of Hashtags from Tweets with Apache Spark. The Application gets the Hashtags from Kafka and everything works fine until the reduceByKey Function. (I know that there is a direct connection betwenn Twitter and Spark)

Without this Function the result is like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1483986210000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(Presse,1)
(Trump,1)
(TheResistanceGQ,1)
(MerylStreep,1)
(theresistance,1)
(Theranos,1)
(Russian,1)
(Trump,1)
(trump,1)
(Üstakıl,1)
...
```

What i need is that similiar Hastags get count and displayed, therefore I need the reduceByKey Function, but i get following error:

```
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (mapToPair at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:106) finished in 0,377 s
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set()
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[4] at reduceByKey at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:113), which has no missing parents
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.2 KB, free 899.7 MB)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1948.0 B, free 899.7 MB)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:56435 (size: 1948.0 B, free: 899.7 MB)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (ShuffledRDD[4] at reduceByKey at JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:113)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, partition 0, ANY, 5800 bytes)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 2 non-empty blocks out of 2 blocks
17/01/09 19:28:54 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 5 ms
17/01/09 19:28:54 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/util/SafeUtils
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2338)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
...
```

Here is my code:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.streaming;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import scala.Tuple2;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Consumes messages from one or more topics in Kafka and does wordcount.
 */

public final class JavaDirectKafkaWordCount {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String brokers = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092";
        String topics = "topicMontag";

        // Create context with a 2 seconds batch interval
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");

        // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, String.class,
                StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicsSet);

        messages.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.println(
                    "--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size() + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
            // rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record._2));
        });

        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });

        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(String x) {
                return Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator();
            }
        });

        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
            }
        });

        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> result = wordCounts.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                return new Integer(i1 + i2);
            }
        });

        //wordCounts.print();
        result.print();
        // PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new
        // FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
        // System.setOut(out);

        // Start the computation

        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-examples_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maybe somebody has an idea? Thanks ...

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` has a very specific meaning and cause. What's the rest of the log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with wrong pom.xml definition.

At first, `<version>2.11.0-M4</version>` in scala-xml - replace it with version 2.10 or you will have other errors

Your issue is that you are using dependency `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:jar:0.8.2.2` which has `net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0` as it's dependency. Spark 2 uses `net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0`. Unfortunatelly Maven resolves this library to lower version, which cannot be used with Spark 2

Steps to make your project working:

1. Scala-XML must be in version 2.10 OR upgrade Spark to Scala 2.11
2. Remove Kafka dependency
3. Provide consistent Spark version for all Spark artifacts - Spark streaming, Spark Core, Spark Streaming Kafka, Spark Examples. All of them should have the same version

Helpful Maven goals to investigate problems with dependencies:

1. `mvn dependency:tree`
2. `mvn dependency:resolve`

Example pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I tried many many different versions in the dependencies, but this combination works fine! Thank you very much!